# I'm Getting following error message from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1] C:\Users\Aabiance Tech001.android\build-cache\ca50fded329e9266bdc24d11405eb6611a4a3b40\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.gridlayout" to force usage

Comment: i'm new to android so please help me!! :-)

Comment: In your build,gradle change this property minSdkVersion to 9. This problem is because you have a dependency which is android.support.v7.gridlayout with a minSdkVersion higher than your project.

Comment: can you post your gradle.build file

Answer (score 2):

Change minSdkVersion in `build.gradle (app)` file from 7  to 9.
How to do it:

1. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd>
2. Search '**build**'
3. Select `build.gradle app`
4. change value of `minSdkVersion` from **7** to **9** inside `defaultConfig { }`
5. then **Sync Now**

Comment: @AbdulKawee Don't worry brother. I think he/she is newbie thats why just tell.

Comment: And if you still have problem, flag my comment I don't mind it.

Comment: No i wont flag, but these type of comments make bad impacts

Comment: For newbie, If you find this is answer for your question, up-vote as press by up arrow click.

Answer (score 0):

Change minSdkVersion value and Read minSdkVersion Information!

```
<manifest>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" /> 
  ...
</manifest>
```

[image: minSdkVersion]
[uses-sdk-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)